# Why is `mfix` not total in `MaybeT`

Tags: haskell, monads, monadfix

The [transformers implementation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe.html#line-186) of `MonadFix` for `MaybeT` fails if the function ever evaluates to `Nothing`. Why is `Nothing` not propagating over `mfix`?

```
mfix' :: MonadFix m => (a -> MaybeT m a) -> MaybeT m a
mfix' f = MaybeT $ mfix $ \case
  Nothing -> return Nothing
  Just x -> runMaybeT $ f x
```

There must be a good reason that I do not see because `ListT` does not implement `MonadFix` at all, and `Maybe` implements it [in the same way](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.Fix.html#line-66) as above.

Comment: Clarification: by "in the same way as above", I suppose you mean "fails if the function ever evaluates to `Nothing`"?

Comment: Can you give a concrete function which causes the existing `MaybeT` implementation of `mfix` to throw its error, witnessing the partiality? I tried, and returning `Nothing` simply wasn't enough; e.g. `mfix (\x -> MaybeT [Nothing]) :: MaybeT [] ()` works just fine. On the other hand, it is easy to observe your implementation being partial; e.g. `mfix' (\x -> MaybeT [Nothing]) :: MaybeT [] ()` (the exact same call, but with `mfix'` instead of `mfix`) never returns.

Comment: Yes. I have a theory: the argument of `mfix :: Maybe a -> m (Maybe a)` can only be one of 2 kinds of functions: it can either pattern  match over the argument in which case `mfix` evaluates to bottom, or it is a constant function in which case we `mfix` just evaluates to the value. The implementation I present above wraps the function in a pattern match, thereby making `mfix` always a bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is just that the `error` message is misleading. Let's just focus on `MonadFix Maybe`. The argument to `mfix` can be one of four things.

1. It can be strict in the input: `f _|_ = _|_` or "`f` needs to evaluate its input to decide whether it will return `Nothing` or `Just`"

   ```
   \x -> if x then Nothing else Just True
   \x -> x `seq` Nothing
   \x -> x `seq` Just x
   ```
2. It can be `const Nothing`.
3. It can be `Just . f` where `f` is not strict.

   ```
   Just . (1:)
   ```
4. It can be `Just . f` where `f` is strict.

   ```
   Just
   ```

If the function is strict, then the whole thing blows up in an infinite loop (just like `fix`), and the error isn't seen because we don't know whether we would have had a `Nothing` or a `Just`. If it is `const Nothing`, the function never actually tries to evaluate the `error` and nothing happens. If it is `Just . f` and `f` is not strict, then it's just `Just $ fix f` (as per the laws: `mfix $ return . f = return $ fix f`). And, if `f` is strict, we get `Just _|_` (again, per the laws). Notice that we never see the `error` triggered.

Similar reasoning works for `MonadFix (MaybeT m)`. I think this time it's better just with an example:

```
runMaybeT $ mfix $ \x -> MaybeT $
             (x `seq` Nothing) :
             Nothing           :
             (Just (1:x))      :
             (Just x)          :
             (x `seq` [])
```

Each of the four cases I listed above are in that list. The first element of the result is an infinite loop. The second is `Nothing`. The third is `repeat 1`, and the fourth is `Just` an infinite loop. Trying to access the "elements" beyond that triggers another infinite loop, this time caused by `[]`'s `MonadFix` and not `MaybeT`'s. Again, I don't believe it's possible to trigger the `error`, because the function would have to force the argument after already deciding that the result was `Nothing`.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `bomb` is indeed very confusing in the quoted library definition, though the function itself is correctly implemented. By monotonicity, any function `f` that satisfies `f undefined = Nothing` has to equal `const Nothing`. Thus, the fixed-point computation will simply produce the correct answer of `Nothing` wrapped up in the transformer stack.

For details, see section 4.9 of [this work](http://leventerkok.github.io/papers/erkok-thesis.pdf), though the original definition omits the constructors for clarity and the name `ErrT` is used instead of `MaybeT`. (MTL didn't exist back in those days!) The definition there is given as follows:

```
mfixErrM :: (α → ErrT m α) → ErrT m α
mfixErrM f = mfixM (f · unErr)
     where unErr (Ok a) = a
```

There's also a proof in appendix [B.7](http://leventerkok.github.io/papers/erkok-thesis.pdf) to show that this is a valid value-recursion operator for `ErrT m` whenever the underlying `mfixM` is a valid value-recursion operator for `m`.

Comment: While you're here.... Would you care to check that the `MonadFix Tree` instance in the latest version of `containers` is valid? I waved my hands a bit and added it without a proper proof.

Comment: @dfeuer That definition looks good to me! While I haven't carried out the proof, I'm also confident it is also the unique such operator. It would be a nice exercise to show uniqueness using a similar argument to the one given for the list monad in Proposition 4.3.3 of http://leventerkok.github.io/papers/erkok-thesis.pdf

Comment: thanks! I'm confident that it's unique up to laziness details. However, there may be some wiggle room in the laziness.

Comment: One can imagine using a lazier version of `(!!)` as you walk through the children. Is that what you're referring to as the laziness details? I doubt it'd make any difference though, since the spine of the list is well defined at that point.

Comment: For lists, the next cons is calculated from the current element. In a tree, perhaps the next cons in a forest could be calculated from the left instead of from above. I don't know if it makes any difference; I don't have much intuition about `MonadFix`. I also find it hard to imagine a situation where the instances for lists, trees, etc., would be useful.

Comment: Once you compute `f undefined`, you will know exactly what the shape of that forest is at the top-level, i.e., exactly how many elements it has or if it's terminating etc. by monotonicity. So, it doesn't matter at all. I do, however, agree that the tree/list/rose-tree etc. instances are unlikely to be useful. All examples I've seen for such esoteric cases are more or less artificial. The only example I know that is "useful" is that for Fudgets, which is a kind of a "tree" and models a term-semantics for basic IO; discussed in Section 4.8 of the thesis.