# Is mfix for Maybe impossible to be nontrivially total?

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type, halting-problem, fixpoint-combinators

Since `Nothing >>= f = Nothing` for every `f`, the following trivial definition is suitable for `mfix`:

```
mfix _ = Nothing
```

But this has no practical use, so we have the following nontotal definition:

```
mfix f = let a = f (unJust a) in a where
    unJust (Just x) = x
    unJust Nothing = errorWithoutStackTrace "mfix Maybe: Nothing"
```

It would be nice if `mfix f` returned `Nothing` if this `let`-clause wouldn't halt. (For example, `f = Just . (1+)`)
Is this impossible because the Halting Problem is unsolvable?

Comment: You may also like [Why is `mfix` not total in `MaybeT`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49613641/791604), though that question focuses on the (unreachable) error call rather than on infinite loops.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the `MonadFix` laws says that the monadic fixpoint must coincide with the pure fixpoint when the monadic action is pure:

```
mfix (return . f) = return (fix f)
```

Because of this, the following is required:

```
mfix (Just . (1+)) = mfix (return . (1+))
                   = return (fix (1+))
                   = Just (fix (1+))
```

And `fix (1+)` is indeed bottom. So for your proposed function, the laws specify exactly how `mfix` must behave (and it does behave this way).

Independently of whether the instance is law-abiding, we can ask whether we like the laws, or perhaps whether it might be useful to have *another* function, with a different name and different laws, that behaves as you propose; e.g. in particular these two calls should behave like this:

```
mfix' (Just . (1+)) = Nothing
mfix' (Just . const 1) = Just 1
```

This is impossible to implement for exactly the reason you say: the halting problem tells us that it's not possible to know for sure whether `fix f` will loop or finish for arbitrary `f`. We can approximate this function in a variety of ways, but all will eventually fall short of perfection in this regard.